# When does US Patent 7,222,078 expire?

Tags: us7222078, lodsys, expiry

Lodsys have been using this patent to sue app developers for damages relating to the use of In-App Purchases. According to [this site](http://aeonlaw.com/in-app-purchase-patent/), the patent expired 6th August 2012 due to a terminal disclaimer linked to [another patent they hold](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US5999908).

Is the expiration date correct? If it is, does this mean any new app that uses the In-App Purchase method is not infringing?

[Google Patents US 7,222,078](http://www.google.co.uk/patents/US7222078)

Comment: I think there is a typo in the question as originally posted. The li led cite calculated the expiration to be Aug 2012, not 2013. I have not checked beyond that or this would be an anwser.

Comment: Yes you are correct, it should have been 2012. I will change that now, thanks for pointing it out.